# php path to gd library

Tags: php, path, gd

I am trying to use Codeigniter's image manipulation class which of course requires a php image library.

I know I have gd library enabled on my server from running phpinfo();

However, I need to specify the path to the image library in codeigniter, and I don't know where it is installed! The server is under someone else's jurisdiction, so is there any way at all to find out where the gd library is installed without using the command line? It is a linux server.

Thanks.

Comment: GD should be compiled into PHP, so there shouldn't be a location to specify. Do you mean ImageMagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GD is compiled with PHP, and is used internally, there is no need to supply a path for GD what so ever, on CI's Manual it states:

> library_path : Sets the server path to your ImageMagick or NetPBM library. If you use either of those libraries you must supply the path.

Hint: you are not using *ImageMagick* or *NetPBM*

If you mean ImageMagick, you can locate the binaries you can try the following command:

```
locate imagemagick
```

but they are usually located in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/X11R6/bin/`

Comment: Right, but if I leave out $config['library_path'] it gives me an error (from $this->image_lib->display_errors())

'The path to your image library is not correct. Please set the correct path in your image preferences.'

Comment: what is `$config['library_path']` set to?

Comment: Ah I've got it working... just a typo when declaring the library in $config['image_library']. Sorry. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

did you try `phpinfo();`

you will get the path to where php installed.

if you can access server

try to search for `gd.so`

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gd-library-path-145032/

http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: Hi, yes I've ran phpinfo to get the root path and it tells you that gd is enabled but not the directory in which it is installed. I don't have access to the server.